# Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ui/template/modal/modal-popup.html magento 2.4.0

Tags: magento2.4.0

Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ui/template/modal/modal-popup.html 2.4.0

> custom.js

popupTpl: "ui/template/modal/modal-popup.html",

```
jquery.js:1508 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ui/template/modal/modal-popup.html
at Function.Sizzle.error (jquery.js:1508)
at Sizzle.tokenize (jquery.js:2165)
at Sizzle.select (jquery.js:2586)
at Function.Sizzle (jquery.js:909)
at Function.jQuery.find (jquery-migrate.js:290)
at jQuery.fn.init.find (jquery.js:2832)
at jQuery.fn.init.jQuery.fn.find (jquery-migrate.js:677)
at jQuery.fn.init (jquery.js:2955)
at new jQuery.fn.init (jquery-migrate.js:241)
at jQuery (jquery.js:80)
```

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/widget_modal.html#modal_popupTpl

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to define the popupTpl value if you are going to use default template.

Please remove popupTpl options and try again. If you still face the same issue please share your custom.js file code.

Thanks